# Python/Selenium: Any way to wildcard the end of an xpath? Or search for a specifically formatted piece of an xpath?

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am using python / selenium to archive some posts. They are simple text + images. As the site requires a login, I'm using selenium to access it.

The problem is, the page shows all the posts, and they are only fully readable on clicking a text labeled "read more", which brings up a popup with the full text / images.

So I'm writing a script to scroll the page, click read more, scrape the post, close it, and move on to the next one.

The problem I'm running into, is that each read more button is an identical element:

```
<a href="javascript:;" style="font-weight: 400">read more</a>
```

If I try to loop through them using XPaths, I run into the problem of them being formatted differently as well, for example:

```
//*[@id="page"]/div[2]/article[10]/div[2]/ul/li/a

//*[@id="page"]/div[2]/article[14]/div[2]/p[3]/a
```

I tried formatting my loop to just loop through the article numbers, but of course the xpath's terminate differently. Is there a way I can add a wildcard to the back half of my xpaths? Or search just by the article numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/` is used to go for direct child, use `//` instead to go from `<article>` to the `<a>`

```
//*[@id="page"]/div[2]/article//a[.="read more"]
```

This will give you a list of elements you can iterate. You might be able to remove the `[.="read more"]`, but it might catch unrelated `<a>` tags, depends on the rest of the html structure.

You can also try looking for the `read more` elements directly by text

```
//a[.="read more"]
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much. This xpath formatting is another world for me, still wrapping my head around it. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using CSS Selectors over XPaths. CSS Selector provide faster, cleaner and simpler way to deal with these queries.

```
('a[href^="javascript"]')
```

> This will selects every  element whose href attribute value begins with "javascript" which is what you are looking for...

You can learn more about [Locating Elements by CSS Selectors](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-css-selectors) in selenium here.

```
readMore = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[href^="javascript"]')
```

And about [Locating Hyperlinks by Link Text](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-hyperlinks-by-link-text)

```
readMore_link = driver.find_elements(By.LINK_TEXT, 'javascript')
```